# Как узнать что браузер сделал автозаполнение

Tags: javascript

У нас есть форма, например логинка. В ней два поля ввода: электронный адрес и пароль. И после первого входа я попросил броузер запомнить введённые значения полей по понятным причинам. При повторном открытии логинки в текстовые поля вставятся значения.

Пример когда броузер подставил пароль(обвёл желтым):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу узнать, что броузер сделал это?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, Вам надо смотреть в сторону сессий или cookies. Эти два механизма позволяют делать автозаполнение полей.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Обновил вопрос.  Вот мне необходимо знать, что броузер сделал эту вставку.

Comment: autocomplete event

Comment: В каком контексте нужно решение? Я решал эту задачу в user.js скриптах.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, есть как минимум два варианта решения:

1. Использовать `MutationObserver` на изменение атрибута `value` целевого элемента
2. Использовать `EventListeners` на событие `change` целевого элемента

Конечно, можно вызывать функцию по таймеру, в которой проверять заполненность поля, но мне такое решение не нравится.

Comment: Разве эти события не случаются, когда пользователь руками вводит данные? Т.е. разве можно будет увидеть, что это именно браузер автозаполнил пароль?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Случаются, но это можно выявлять при необходимости. В данном случае это может быть не нужно.

Comment: Значение при автозаполнении   - пустая строка.

Answer (score 0):

После автозаполнения поля браузер меняет цвет фона. Поэтому действенный способ - это в обработчике изменения элемента прорерить не поменялся ли цвет фона элемента:

```
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('password'))
  if (style && style.backgroundColor !== initialBackgroundColor) {
    // сюда попадаем если браузер заполнил автоматически
  }
```

`initialBackgroundColor` - ставим такой как у нас изначально.

Comment: [ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708092/detecting-browser-autofill)

Comment: Ваше решение не работает. Протестировано в Chrome 89.